# Chrome gets hung randomly - Python Selenium Windows

Tags: python, windows, google-chrome, selenium, freeze

We are running a Python Selenium script in Windows Chrome, and are now faced with an issue which we cannot resolve.

The script (medium sized) runs to completion only say 1 in 3 times.
Other times, it freezes in the middle, maybe after 10 steps, or 15 steps- after that there is no response whatsoever.

The only clue we got was that there is an error printed out (usually after 10 minutes of waiting) `access denied`.

After this hanging the only option is to

1. Kill the browser or
2. Kill the process

We tried `--disable-extensions`, and having an `user-dir` etc, but to no avail.

There is an anti-virus (Symantec) running in the machine, which cannot be disabled (enterprise level security settings).

Has anyone faced this issue?
Is there any solution? Please let me know.

Comment: Can you show us your code block please?

Comment: It is inside a secured network, so I cannot take it out. But it is the usual selenium python commands - find_element_by_id, el.click() etc. This hanging happens in different areas also every time - not at the same place.

Comment: did you check your AV windows IO events? you can monitor it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the issue was due to AV. Stopped the anti virus for some time and it is running properly now.